# Subsetting row if NA is present if there is more than one occurance of another variable of interest?

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

```
   Indicator Name Examine
1           Alpha      NA
2            Beta    2013
3            Beta    2017
4            Beta      NA
5         Charlie    2013
6         Charlie    2017
7         Charlie      NA
8           Delta    2016
9            Echo    2016
10           <NA>      NA
11           <NA>      NA
12        Foxtrot    2007
13        Foxtrot      NA
```

Here, I would like to remove rows where an `NA` is present in `Examine`, if `Indicator Name` has more than one entry, **except** for `NA`.

So, rows 4, 7, and 13 would be removed.

Sample df:

```
structure(list(`Indicator Name` = c("Alpha", "Beta", "Beta", 
"Beta", "Charlie", "Charlie", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo", NA, 
NA, "Foxtrot", "Foxtrot"), Examine = c(NA, 2013, 2017, NA, 2013, 
2017, NA, 2016, 2016, NA, NA, 2007, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 13L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After grouping by 'Indicator Name', create a condition in the `filter` to remove NA elements or to keep if `all` elements are `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(`Indicator Name`) %>%
   filter(!is.na(Examine)| all(is.na(Examine)))
```

---

Or using the same logic in `base R`

```
df[with(df, ave(is.na(Examine), `Indicator Name`, FUN = function(x) !x|all(x))),]
```

Comment: Hows does  `all(is.na())` work in this code? More specifically why isn't `is.na(Examine)` sufficient?

Comment: @NelsonGon. The OP wanted to remove NA elements only if there are non-NA elements in the 'Examine',  Thus the first bit of code does that `!is.na(Examine)`, but that will also remove cases where all the elements are NA.  To avoid that, included the OR condition to keep those groups having all NA elements in 'Examine'

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks. I had forgotten all about the grouping bit. Thanks again!